# Redirecting requests to a subfolder

Tags: url-rewriting, iis7, iis

We have multiple WordPress installations on our IIS7 (Windows Server 2008) Server as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/site_one
http://www.example.com/site_two
http://www.example.com/site_three
```

These all work properly. However we would like to configure it so that when users visit the root domain (`http://www.example.com/`) or any page underneath, ie:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/page1
http://www.example.com/page2
```

They would actually see the corresponding pages for `site_two`:

```
http://www.example.com/site_two/
http://www.example.com/site_two/page1
http://www.example.com/site_two/page2
```

How could we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the URL rewrite modile of IIS 7. More info [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tutorial listed here:

http://askwpgirl.com/how-do-i-move-wordpress-from-a-subdirectory-to-the-root-directory/

The only thing I am unsure of is the coexistence of this setup with other WordPress sites in other subdirectories off the root. If it doesn't work, you can always delete the index.php file that you're copying to the root to revert.